# maven not updating jar in local repo with new build number

Tags: java, maven-3

i have added the build number plugin in the pom of one of my modules as follows:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>validate</phase>        
                <goals>
                    <goal>create</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <doCheck>false</doCheck>
            <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
            <format>${project.version}.{0,number}</format>
            <items>
                <item>buildNumber</item>
            </items>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Also i tried that the jar built is kept inside a folder ./ and the jar also gets buildnumber appended to its version name  by using the jar plugin as:

```
<plugin>

    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
          <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
        </manifestEntries>
      </archive>
      <outputDirectory>target/${buildNumber}</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The build works fine and the jar is created inside target as target//myjar-.jar
(Where version is 1.0 suppose and buildnumber is incremented with each build starting with 1)
However in local repository the jar is stored as package//myjar-.jar , i.e the buildnumber is not getting added there. 
Is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, everything seems fine (artifact in target directory, manifest etc), except the filename in local repository is not what you want, am I right?

If so, and if I remember correctly, that's exactly it should work.  Artifact file name in local/remote repository is generated according to artifact name, version number, modifier and qualifier, and timestamp in case of snapshot.  It have nothing to do with the output filename in the target directory.

Comment: thanks Adrian, if it is so then how to do i specify an artifact as a dependency to another with the new build number if this is not stored in my local repo? E.g if during build of jar A the generated artifact is A-1.0-1 then since in local repo its stored as A-1.0 so i cannot specify A-1.0-1 as a dependency..so what's the use of this plugin then..is it only for creating the final war and not the individual jars? Thanks.

Comment: You should treat the artifact in your local repo "virtually" have no name.  Artifact is located just by GroupID + ArtifactID + version + Modifier/Qualifier.  All of them have nothing to do with the filename.  The use of the plugin all depends on your usage, I believe most people use it to put build number in some resources or in META-INF.  To achieve what you wnat, you need to have build number being part of the version (or qualifier?).  I don't recommend such approach as it does not work well with existing Maven.  However u may look into maven release plugin for updating version on the fly.